# How to send graphql query by postman?

Tags: graphql, postman

I use

```
POST type
URL http://######/graphql
Body: 
query: "query: "{'noteTypes':  {'name', 'label', 'labelColor', 'groupName', 'groupLabel', 'imageUrl'}}"
```

But it return 
**"message": "Must provide query string."**

Answer (score 146):

---

There's a better way to do it using the REST client [**Insomnia**](https://insomnia.rest/)

Docs are here, how to send graphql queries: https://support.insomnia.rest/article/61-graphql

---

Below are the steps for postman

***Step 1.***

Run the GraphiQL in Chrome, open the Chrome Dev Console, click the Network tab, and make the query from graphiql, when you make the query, network tab will show the graphql request...

[image]

***Step 2.***

From the `graphql` request copy the request query, Select the `Copy as cURL (cmd)`

[image]

***Step 3.***

Open Postman, In the Top-Left click on the `Import` button, after you click `Import` you have to click the `Paste Raw Text`, and paste the copied `cURL` request as done in step2 after it's done click the `Import`

[image]

***Step 4.***

Postman is ready to send the Graphql request, Just Click on the `Send` Button, you will see the `Response` in the Response Box in body as below

[image]

***Step 5.***

To see how the query is being sent click on the `Body` tab next to `Headers`, you will get know how to provide the fields from postman in JSON format.

e.g: `edges {\n node {\n id\n jobId\n }\n`, If you want to view another field then you need to add it in with the suffix `\n`

like if need `name` then : `edges {\n node {\n id\n jobId\n name\n }\n`

`\n` here just means to represent a new line. Instead, you can make it simpler by providing a clear and illustrative JSON like below

**===========================================================================**

***Note***: The body type must be raw with `application/json` content-type. So, the query must be a valid JSON with quotes `".."`

```
{  
   "query":"{viewer {user {edges {node {id jobId name }}}}}"
}
```

**===========================================================================**

[image]

*you can directly start from `step 5` if you know how to send the query in body and other things too that needs to be required while making a request from postman*

[image]

With simplified JSON

[image]

Comment: While using the same steps I am getting:, Error while importing Curl: 2option-less arguments found. Only one is supported (the URL)

Comment: Copy as cURL(bash) worked for me, instead of Copy as cURL(cmd), using chrome postman app on windows 10 OS

Comment: I just change the Content-Type with application/graphql to application/json, and it work, I think the postman default setting this as application/graphql is so bad.

Comment: Keep in mind that GraphQL requests are POST requests. Not GET.

Answer (score 52):

**You don't need INSOMNIA in case the GraphQL server responds to `Content-type: application/graphql` or *`postman.setEnvironmentVariable`***,

Just do it:

In Headers tab: 

`Content-Type: application/graphql`

In Body tab, "raw" selected, put your query

[image]

Comment: i get "No query string was present" trying this

Comment: Works perfectly for me! Using Node.js with express and express-graphql dependencies.

Answer (score 26):

Adding this for anyone searching on the topic ... you can utilize and test GraphQL calls far better and more easily with Insomnia:

https://insomnia.rest

It's been fantastic for GraphQL development.

Comment: Thank you! Here is the doc regarding GraphQL: https://support.insomnia.rest/article/61-graphql

Answer (score 20):

There's a simple way to do it. Use a pre-request script to stringify the payload ([source](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2390)).

**Step 1.**

In the body of the request put a placeholder for the payload.

```
{
    "query":{{query}}
}
```

**Step 2.**

Create the payload in the pre-request script and store it in an environment variable.

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("query", JSON.stringify(
`
{
  search(query: "test", type: ISSUE, first: 10) {
    issueCount
    edges {
      node {
        ... on Issue {
          title
          id
          state
          closed
          repository {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
`
));
```

That's it.

Comment: This is working like a charm and avoids to go through the hassle of all the manual steps described in the previous answers! Thank you.

Comment: We must be using an older version of graphql or having a specific setup but it finally worked with the above proposal and a tiny change "body" instead of "query": 

> placeholder
>     {
>       "body":{{query}}
>     }

Answer (score 15):

UPDATE 8-2019 - I know this is old, but regarding POSTMAN, if you haven't figured it out already, they do have a graphql (beta) option for posting body. There is no need to add any additional headers.

[image]

Comment: Nowadays Postman's GraphQL body type aren't in beta anymore! It is a stable option available, as shown [here](https://youtu.be/7pUbezVADQs)

Answer (score 11):

### UPDATE 2:

It's not practical use POSTMAN, because the are working yet in a easy way to add headers, that take longtime, and i think POSTMAN is not made for work naturally with graphql,

you can follow the progress about that here:
   https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1669

I recommend to use another packages plugin like:

```
the best (like postman , but profile and sync price 5$ monthly):
   https://insomnia.rest/
others:
   https://github.com/andev-software/graphql-ide
   https://github.com/imolorhe
```

for graphiql (no add headers possibility)  you  need to set  three things (it's not easy to type):

1. Header:

   Content-Type: application/json
2. Body:

   Choose Ray < optiongroup

   Choose JSON (application/json)  < selectbox
3. Compose javascript object with "query" and the "value" of your graph query. Like all objects in js it'sneeded the propery and the value , in this case "quote" is the property, the value must be with double quotes.  Inside the value (graphl string) you dont compose  js objects, so you dont need use doble quotes, it's just a string.

   {"query":"{ allQuotes {     text   }   }" }

   the problem is you need type all in a single line, no like grapIql... there is a post requirement in postman github so is easy work with graphql:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Postman just released [inbuilt GraphQL support](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1669#issuecomment-494384520) in version 7.2.

> This version supports
>
> - Sending GraphQL queries in request body as POST requests
> - Support for GraphQL variables
> - Creating APIs in Postman with GraphQL schema type
> - Query autocompletion integrated with user defined GraphQL schemas
>
> Please give it a try and give us your feedback on the tracking thread on [our community forum](https://community.getpostman.com/t/graphql-support-in-postman-available-for-early-access-on-canary-channel/5524)

Answer (score 9):

I faced the same problem when I try to used `graphQl` query using `POSTMAN`, 
In POSTMAN send data from the `raw` tab with `json` type.

**Query Command:**

```
{"query":"{user(id:902){id,username,DOB}}"}
```

**Mutations Command:**

```
{ "query": "mutation {createMutations(reviewer:36, comments:\"hello\",data_id: 1659, approved: true ){id}}" }

       #commnent: String Type
       #data_id:Int Type
       #approved:Boolean Type
```

Comment: Could you please tell us how to pass an object? Here if reviewer and comments are part of the new input object the how the command will be?

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Visual Studio, I have written a plugin to convert GraphQL to Restful body

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=orasik.graphql-to-rest-queries

[image]

Comment: You saved  my weekend :)

Answer (score 5):

Postman has recently launched its out of box support for GraphQL: https://blog.getpostman.com/2019/06/18/postman-v7-2-supports-graphql/

Below is the screenshot of testing GraphQL locally:

[image]

**Note**: Running GraphQL locally using spring-boot https://www.baeldung.com/spring-graphql

Answer (score 3):

Deriving from [Estevão Lucas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49988524/6143656).

You can also use header `Content-type: application/json` on postman

And define the body with:

```
{
    "query": "{ your_query }"
}
```

This is easily constructed on the client side to form a request payload.

e.g.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Could you please tell me how to pass an object. For example, email and password as part of another object then how request payload change?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but what I'm understanding is you want to pass an object e.g. `credentials` which has the property of `password` and `email`. In that case, you may need to define an input type object in your mutation. and use the `$input: <yourinputmutation>!` or something like that in the query.

Comment: Fore more code example here: https://github.com/roelzkie15/chatta-api/blob/master/services/messaging/tests.py#L14

Answer (score 1):

Checkout https://github.com/hasura/graphqurl - curl for GraphQL:

- CLI for making GraphQL queries with autocomplete
- Run GraphiQL locally against any endpoint (with custom headers)
- Use as a library with nodejs or from the browser
- Supports subscriptions

I am one of the authors.

```
gq https://gentle-anchorage-72051.herokuapp.com/v1alpha1/graphql -i
```

[image: GraphiQL with headers]

Answer (score 0):

IF we can pass header type, Then add the header **Content-type: application/graphql**

Below link can be used as reference:
[link description here](https://www.codetraveler.io/2019/01/12/how-to-use-postman-with-a-graphql-api/)

Answer (score 0):

By adding header we can run graphql query in the postman

`Content-type: application/graphql`