# Graphql send POST with variables in Postman as text

Tags: java, graphql, postman, graphql-java

I have endpoint where my request works when it is:

```
query {
    getItem(dictionaryType: "test1") {
        code
        name
        description
    }
}
```

It works fine, see:

[image]

I want to test variable - so i want to change it to sth like:

```
query {
    getItem($dictionaryType: String) {
        code
        name
        description
    }
}
variables {
    dictionaryType: "test1"
}
```

**I do not want to use any other tool than postman, or i would rather not use other format than text.**
When executing the second ouput i get following error:

```
"errors": [
    {
        "message": "Invalid Syntax",
        "locations": [
            {
                "line": 2,
                "column": 9,
                "sourceName": null
            }
        ],
```

How to fix the syntax of the request?

[image]

**Edit:**
I have even problem with request with syntax like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50043390/4983983
`query { getDataTypes }`
To translate it to json For example: 
`{"query": "{getDataTypes}"}` 
Does not work and gives JSON parse error: 
`Cannot deserialize instance of`java.lang.String`out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of`java.lang.String`out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream`
 error.

See:
[image]
[image]

Currently the `code` for `Posts` endpoints looks like:

```
@PostMapping("graphql")
public ResponseEntity<Object> getResource(@RequestBody String query) {
    ExecutionResult result = graphQL.execute(query);
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

If i change it to:

```
@PostMapping("graphql")
public ResponseEntity<Object> getResource(@RequestBody Object query) { // String query
    ExecutionResult result;
    if (query instanceof String) {
        result = graphQL.execute(query.toString());
    } else{
        Map b = (HashMap) query;
        result = graphQL.execute(b.get("query").toString());
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Now it seems only `json` versions works. Cause when i use text i get:

```
"status": 415,
"error": "Unsupported Media Type",
"message": "Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
"path": "/graphql"
```

Is there other config option for that matter?? I don't know if the `variables` will be well handled in the last example.

Comment: You need to send a proper JSON request, something like `{"query": "...", "variables": "..."}`

Comment: Isn't the syntax for variable replacement something like `{{dictionaryType}}` ?

Comment: Why not text? For other request it works.

Comment: @Arnaud see here: https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables

Comment: Note that example I give - the `...` in the query will contain the actual query.

Comment: Yeah - i understood that. But why if other request as `plain text` works - now when i add `variables` it stop to work? It should work - but my syntax is probably wrong.

Comment: Because the variables request needs to be able to be split out from the main query, you can't just tag it on to the end.

Comment: So there is not possible for me to do a `POST` as text?
Could you post an `answer` providing how this `json` should look like? I tried it myself - but i did not work. I updated the question with image - to show you - that request before works with plain text.

Comment: I have even problem with request like ```query {
 getDataTypes
}```
To translate it to `json`
For example:
```{"query": "getDataTypes"}```
Does not work and gives 
```JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream```
error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send graphql query by postman?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42520663/how-to-send-graphql-query-by-postman)

Comment: This is  other issue - cause i get an exception when trying to get it to `json` and i ask for plain text answer. I edited the question.

Comment: What content type did you send with the request?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187042/discussion-between-yami-and-davidg).

Comment: I found the reason and updated the question - how can i configure it nicely ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to update postman version to 7.2.
Postman now supports graphql requests.

https://blog.getpostman.com/2019/06/18/postman-v7-2-supports-graphql/

refer to Image below.

[image]

Comment: Cool - when i writed this post it was not there.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with similar to below sample

> {     "Query":"query interview($id:ID!){ interview(interviewGuid: $id) {
>   interviewGuid interviewCode  interviewTitle interviewOwnerGuid
>   interviewStartDate interviewEndDate}}",
>     "Variables":{"id":"725000ae-ba39-45a5-a10f-79e5b27fe747"} }

[image]