# How to test graphql + apollo server for upload file mutation using postman?

Tags: graphql

I using apollo server, and have this mutation :

```
mutation {
  updateData(
    file1: fileOne,
    file2: fileTwo,
    file3: fileThree,
    payload: {
      id: "7e3583b4-5673-48df-a3cf-44a4ec33f0e1"
    }
  ){
    isSuccess
    error
    data
  }
}
```

I want to test it using postman, because i didnt find any clue test it using graphql playground.

I already find how to test graphql from postman, but it doesn't contains information about file upload. [graphql postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42520663/how-to-send-graphql-query-by-postman)

I have an idea from [apollo-upload-client](https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client) to post using multipart-formdata but it still fail.

please help how to test graphql with apollo server for upload file mutation using postman?

thanks

Comment: Are you fixed on Postman or can you try another REST client? I know how to do this using Insomnia - it is not a very pretty solution but it has worked for me. I vaguely recall having trouble achieving this on Postman altogether due to some bug or limitation in Postman.

Comment: i found some clue from internet and it works, using postman formdata must add multer on server.

Comment: @Avius Can u pls help me with insomina ? how to do it there ?

Comment: @yozawiratama can you please let us know your solution as I am in the same issue and need someone to help

Comment: okay, sorry for late reply

Answer (score 0):

I need to understand about how file upload works in node js (because I use nodejs ini this case)

1. I install multer for file upload middleware using nodejs and expressjs, if you use other framework or programming language, just try adjust it
2. In postman I use formdata

you can find the good step by step here

[Upload file graphql using postman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61892790/553779)