# Configuring GraphiQL for AWS App Sync end point with AWS token authentication

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync, graphiql

I am trying to learn GraphQL and I created an App Sync service in AWS, I am using the GraphiQL (Playground) client App, and I cannot get the header correct for the authentication, I keep getting unauthorized error. How do I structure the Header JSON for APP ID and API TOKEN.

Thanks Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a query on the AppSync console, monitor it through the developers tools and then continue with the steps described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42523727/4692302). In this way you can see which headers are required and how are they provided.

Comment: Spot on Neill, thanks.  I used developer tools to see the request Header and then added to it GraphiQL