# Using GitHub GraphQL API programmatically, getting a Bad Request with RestTemplate.execute, but works ok on Postman

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, github-api

I'm trying to consume [GitHub's v4 API using GraphQL](https://developer.github.com/v4/) from within a Spring Boot application (namely, my app is a server that is trying to consume the API on a Service as part of resolving a GET request on one of the app's controllers).

I tried the following test POST request on Postman, getting the data I was expecting successfully:

```
POST /graphql HTTP/1.1
Host: api.github.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer [MY PERSONAL GITHUB TOKEN]
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.20.1
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 55f54f00-83f6-4acb-a6f8-4a3bde9147e7,abb6f600-8b79-4697-bd31-e04836386a24
Host: api.github.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 264
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache

query{repository(owner:"ccjmk", name:"super-happiness"){object(expression:"master"){... on Commit{history{totalCount}}}}}
```

Response:

```
{"data":{"repository":{"object":{"history":{"totalCount":19}}}}}
```

(I don't see any notable headers but I could add anything that might be valuable)

Then, on the Java end, I tried this in the service: (I also tried hitting the v3 API successfully, adding the method used on the service too for reference)

```
    @Override
    public String fetchCommitsv3(String ownerUsername, String repository) {

        final String uri = String.format("https://api.github.com/repos/%s/%s/commits", ownerUsername, repository);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<String> fetchCommitsv4(String ownerUsername, String repository) {

        final String uri = String.format("https://api.github.com/graphql");
        String query = "query{repository(owner:\""+ownerUsername+"\", name:\""+repository+"\"){object(expression:\"master\"){... on Commit{history{totalCount}}}}}";

        String gitHubToken = [MY GITHUB TOKEN];

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory());
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        //headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer "+gitHubToken);
        headers.set("Authorization","Bearer "+gitHubToken);
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(query, headers);

        ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
        return result;
    }
```

That's triggering a 400 Bad Request reponse, at the end the full post. To me, both requests look the same, but they are surely different, only I can't pin-point where! Any help would be much appreciated, because I'm sure

---

SpringBoot Log:

```
2020-01-07 16:48:24.419 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/tdd/insights/github/v4/commits/ccjmk/super-happiness]
2020-01-07 16:48:24.432 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /tdd/insights/github/v4/commits/ccjmk/super-happiness
2020-01-07 16:48:24.450 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.penguin.formula.tdd.web.controller.InsightsController.commitsv4(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception]
2020-01-07 16:48:24.451 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/tdd/insights/github/v4/commits/ccjmk/super-happiness] is: -1
2020-01-07 16:51:35.166 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Created POST request for "https://api.github.com/graphql"
2020-01-07 16:51:35.169 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Setting request Accept header to [text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*]
2020-01-07 16:51:35.182 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Writing [query{repository(owner:"ccjmk", name:"super-happiness"){object(expression:"master"){... on Commit{history{totalCount}}}}}] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@7dcd6967]
2020-01-07 16:51:35.404 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] o.a.h.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies  : CookieSpec selected: default
2020-01-07 16:51:35.607 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] o.a.h.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache   : Auth cache not set in the context
2020-01-07 16:51:35.644 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection request: [route: {s}->https://api.github.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 5; total allocated: 0 of 10]
2020-01-07 16:51:35.861 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://api.github.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 5; total allocated: 1 of 10]
2020-01-07 16:51:35.889 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Opening connection {s}->https://api.github.com:443
2020-01-07 16:51:35.928 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] .i.c.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator : Connecting to api.github.com/140.82.118.5:443
2020-01-07 16:51:35.930 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] o.a.h.c.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory   : Connecting socket to api.github.com/140.82.118.5:443 with timeout 0
2020-01-07 16:51:35.983 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] o.a.h.c.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory   : Enabled protocols: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
2020-01-07 16:51:35.988 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] o.a.h.c.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory   : Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
2020-01-07 16:51:35.993 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] o.a.h.c.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory   : Starting handshake
2020-01-07 16:51:36.648 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] o.a.h.c.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory   : Secure session established
2020-01-07 16:51:36.651 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] o.a.h.c.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory   :  negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2
2020-01-07 16:51:36.654 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] o.a.h.c.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory   :  negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
2020-01-07 16:51:36.658 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] o.a.h.c.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory   :  peer principal: CN=*.github.com, O="GitHub, Inc.", L=San Francisco, ST=California, C=US
2020-01-07 16:51:36.661 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] o.a.h.c.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory   :  peer alternative names: [*.github.com, github.com]
2020-01-07 16:51:36.665 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] o.a.h.c.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory   :  issuer principal: CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
2020-01-07 16:51:36.700 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] .i.c.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator : Connection established 192.168.1.98:48784<->140.82.118.5:443
2020-01-07 16:51:36.702 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Executing request POST /graphql HTTP/1.1
2020-01-07 16:51:36.705 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2020-01-07 16:51:36.743 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> POST /graphql HTTP/1.1
2020-01-07 16:51:36.745 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> Accept: text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*
2020-01-07 16:51:36.747 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> Authorization: Bearer {{MY PERSONAL TOKEN}}
2020-01-07 16:51:36.748 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Type: application/json
2020-01-07 16:51:36.752 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Charset: big5, big5-hkscs, cesu-8, euc-jp, euc-kr, gb18030, gb2312, gbk, ibm-thai, ibm00858, ibm01140, ibm01141, ibm01142, ibm01143, ibm01144, ibm01145, ibm01146, ibm01147, ibm01148, ibm01149, ibm037, ibm1026, ibm1047, ibm273, ibm277, ibm278, ibm280, ibm284, ibm285, ibm290, ibm297, ibm420, ibm424, ibm437, ibm500, ibm775, ibm850, ibm852, ibm855, ibm857, ibm860, ibm861, ibm862, ibm863, ibm864, ibm865, ibm866, ibm868, ibm869, ibm870, ibm871, ibm918, iso-2022-cn, iso-2022-jp, iso-2022-jp-2, iso-2022-kr, iso-8859-1, iso-8859-13, iso-8859-15, iso-8859-2, iso-8859-3, iso-8859-4, iso-8859-5, iso-8859-6, iso-8859-7, iso-8859-8, iso-8859-9, jis_x0201, jis_x0212-1990, koi8-r, koi8-u, shift_jis, tis-620, us-ascii, utf-16, utf-16be, utf-16le, utf-32, utf-32be, utf-32le, utf-8, windows-1250, windows-1251, windows-1252, windows-1253, windows-1254, windows-1255, windows-1256, windows-1257, windows-1258, windows-31j, x-big5-hkscs-2001, x-big5-solaris, x-compound_text, x-euc-jp-linux, x-euc-tw, x-eucjp-open, x-ibm1006, x-ibm1025, x-ibm1046, x-ibm1097, x-ibm1098, x-ibm1112, x-ibm1122, x-ibm1123, x-ibm1124, x-ibm1166, x-ibm1364, x-ibm1381, x-ibm1383, x-ibm300, x-ibm33722, x-ibm737, x-ibm833, x-ibm834, x-ibm856, x-ibm874, x-ibm875, x-ibm921, x-ibm922, x-ibm930, x-ibm933, x-ibm935, x-ibm937, x-ibm939, x-ibm942, x-ibm942c, x-ibm943, x-ibm943c, x-ibm948, x-ibm949, x-ibm949c, x-ibm950, x-ibm964, x-ibm970, x-iscii91, x-iso-2022-cn-cns, x-iso-2022-cn-gb, x-iso-8859-11, x-jis0208, x-jisautodetect, x-johab, x-macarabic, x-maccentraleurope, x-maccroatian, x-maccyrillic, x-macdingbat, x-macgreek, x-machebrew, x-maciceland, x-macroman, x-macromania, x-macsymbol, x-macthai, x-macturkish, x-macukraine, x-ms932_0213, x-ms950-hkscs, x-ms950-hkscs-xp, x-mswin-936, x-pck, x-sjis_0213, x-utf-16le-bom, x-utf-32be-bom, x-utf-32le-bom, x-windows-50220, x-windows-50221, x-windows-874, x-windows-949, x-windows-950, x-windows-iso2022jp
2020-01-07 16:51:36.755 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Length: 121
2020-01-07 16:51:36.757 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> Host: api.github.com
2020-01-07 16:51:36.759 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
2020-01-07 16:51:36.760 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/1.8.0_232)
2020-01-07 16:51:36.762 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
2020-01-07 16:51:36.770 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 >> "POST /graphql HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:36.773 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept: text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:36.774 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 >> "Authorization: Bearer {{MY PERSONAL TOKEN}}[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:36.776 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:36.781 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Charset: big5, big5-hkscs, cesu-8, euc-jp, euc-kr, gb18030, gb2312, gbk, ibm-thai, ibm00858, ibm01140, ibm01141, ibm01142, ibm01143, ibm01144, ibm01145, ibm01146, ibm01147, ibm01148, ibm01149, ibm037, ibm1026, ibm1047, ibm273, ibm277, ibm278, ibm280, ibm284, ibm285, ibm290, ibm297, ibm420, ibm424, ibm437, ibm500, ibm775, ibm850, ibm852, ibm855, ibm857, ibm860, ibm861, ibm862, ibm863, ibm864, ibm865, ibm866, ibm868, ibm869, ibm870, ibm871, ibm918, iso-2022-cn, iso-2022-jp, iso-2022-jp-2, iso-2022-kr, iso-8859-1, iso-8859-13, iso-8859-15, iso-8859-2, iso-8859-3, iso-8859-4, iso-8859-5, iso-8859-6, iso-8859-7, iso-8859-8, iso-8859-9, jis_x0201, jis_x0212-1990, koi8-r, koi8-u, shift_jis, tis-620, us-ascii, utf-16, utf-16be, utf-16le, utf-32, utf-32be, utf-32le, utf-8, windows-1250, windows-1251, windows-1252, windows-1253, windows-1254, windows-1255, windows-1256, windows-1257, windows-1258, windows-31j, x-big5-hkscs-2001, x-big5-solaris, x-compound_text, x-euc-jp-linux, x-euc-tw, x-eucjp-open, x-ibm1006, x-ibm1025, x-ibm1046, x-ibm1097, x-ibm1098, x-ibm1112, x-ibm1122, x-ibm1123, x-ibm1124, x-ibm1166, x-ibm1364, x-ibm1381, x-ibm1383, x-ibm300, x-ibm33722, x-ibm737, x-ibm833, x-ibm834, x-ibm856, x-ibm874, x-ibm875, x-ibm921, x-ibm922, x-ibm930, x-ibm933, x-ibm935, x-ibm937, x-ibm939, x-ibm942, x-ibm942c, x-ibm943, x-ibm943c, x-ibm948, x-ibm949, x-ibm949c, x-ibm950, x-ibm964, x-ibm970, x-iscii91, x-iso-2022-cn-cns, x-iso-2022-cn-gb, x-iso-8859-11, x-jis0208, x-jisautodetect, x-johab, x-macarabic, x-maccentraleurope, x-maccroatian, x-maccyrillic, x-macdingbat, x-macgreek, x-machebrew, x-maciceland, x-macroman, x-macromania, x-macsymbol, x-macthai, x-macturkish, x-macukraine, x-ms932_0213, x-ms950-hkscs, x-ms950-hkscs-xp, x-mswin-936, x-pck, x-sjis_0213, x-utf-16le-bom, x-utf-32be-bom, x-utf-32le-bom, x-windows-50220, x-windows-50221, x-windows-874, x-windows-949, x-windows-950, x-windows-iso2022jp[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:36.783 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Length: 121[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:36.785 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: api.github.com[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:36.787 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:36.789 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/1.8.0_232)[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:36.791 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:36.793 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:36.795 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 >> "query{repository(owner:"ccjmk", name:"super-happiness"){object(expression:"master"){... on Commit{history{totalCount}}}}}"
2020-01-07 16:51:37.070 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:37.077 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "Date: Tue, 07 Jan 2020 16:51:36 GMT[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:37.083 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:37.087 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Length: 89[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:37.091 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "Server: GitHub.com[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:37.094 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "Status: 400 Bad Request[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:37.097 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "Cache-Control: no-cache[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:37.099 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "X-OAuth-Scopes: read:enterprise, read:org, read:packages, read:repo_hook, read:user, repo[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:37.101 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes: repo[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:37.103 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "X-GitHub-Media-Type: unknown, github.v4[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:37.105 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "X-RateLimit-Limit: 5000[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:37.107 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "X-RateLimit-Remaining: 5000[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:37.109 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "X-RateLimit-Reset: 1578419496[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:37.112 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag, Link, Location, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval, X-GitHub-Media-Type[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:37.114 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:37.116 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:37.118 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "X-Frame-Options: deny[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:37.119 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:37.121 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:37.123 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "Referrer-Policy: origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:37.125 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:37.127 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "X-GitHub-Request-Id: BE90:B6DD:27E5493C:2F86CC08:5E14B718[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:37.129 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
2020-01-07 16:51:37.131 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "{"message":"Problems parsing JSON","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v4"}"
2020-01-07 16:51:37.175 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
2020-01-07 16:51:37.177 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << Date: Tue, 07 Jan 2020 16:51:36 GMT
2020-01-07 16:51:37.178 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
2020-01-07 16:51:37.180 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << Content-Length: 89
2020-01-07 16:51:37.182 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << Server: GitHub.com
2020-01-07 16:51:37.184 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << Status: 400 Bad Request
2020-01-07 16:51:37.185 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << Cache-Control: no-cache
2020-01-07 16:51:37.187 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << X-OAuth-Scopes: read:enterprise, read:org, read:packages, read:repo_hook, read:user, repo
2020-01-07 16:51:37.189 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes: repo
2020-01-07 16:51:37.191 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << X-GitHub-Media-Type: unknown, github.v4
2020-01-07 16:51:37.192 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << X-RateLimit-Limit: 5000
2020-01-07 16:51:37.194 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << X-RateLimit-Remaining: 5000
2020-01-07 16:51:37.195 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << X-RateLimit-Reset: 1578419496
2020-01-07 16:51:37.197 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag, Link, Location, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval, X-GitHub-Media-Type
2020-01-07 16:51:37.199 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
2020-01-07 16:51:37.200 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
2020-01-07 16:51:37.202 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << X-Frame-Options: deny
2020-01-07 16:51:37.204 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
2020-01-07 16:51:37.206 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
2020-01-07 16:51:37.207 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << Referrer-Policy: origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin
2020-01-07 16:51:37.209 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
2020-01-07 16:51:37.210 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << X-GitHub-Request-Id: BE90:B6DD:27E5493C:2F86CC08:5E14B718
2020-01-07 16:51:37.288 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
2020-01-07 16:51:37.336 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : POST request for "https://api.github.com/graphql" resulted in 400 (Bad Request); invoking error handler
2020-01-07 16:51:37.375 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection [id: 0][route: {s}->https://api.github.com:443] can be kept alive indefinitely
2020-01-07 16:51:37.377 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection : http-outgoing-0: set socket timeout to 0
2020-01-07 16:51:37.380 DEBUG 21236 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection released: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://api.github.com:443][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 5; total allocated: 1 of 10]
```

---

Comment: The body seems to be exactly the same indeed, but what strikes me as odd is the `Content-Length`. It is 264 in your Postman example and 121 in your code.

Comment: `query{repository(owner:"ccjmk", name:"super-happiness"){object(expression:"master"){... on Commit{history{totalCount}}}}}` is indeed 121 characters.

Comment: Good catch! I noticed that the content-type on postman doesn't match either. I originally had a "longer" body, with spaces and tabs, and thought it was that, but after sending again the same exact body I pasted here (and on the java app), I noticed that it still gets extra length.

I have been using the GraphQL body setting on Postman, which I thought was merely syntax-highlighting, but after sending that body Raw, it fails, so there's something added there.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42523727/40064 for more details on how to use Postman with GraphQL and a 'Raw' body

Comment: Got it, thanks for the hint on the content-type! It's actually being sent as a json so you gotta jsonify it first. I'll make a proper answer.

Comment: content-length*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, thanks to Wim Deblauwe hinting that Content-Lenghts were off on the JSON request, I noticed the following:

I was using the GraphQL body mode on Postman, which (unbeknownst to me, you gotta read the documentation kids!) actually JSONifies the body before sending it.

Sending this (the GraphQL raw body) as a JSON:

```
query{repository(owner:"ccjmk", name:"super-happiness"){object(expression:"master"){... on Commit{history{totalCount}}}}}
```

Returns 400 Bad Request:

```
{
    "message": "Problems parsing JSON",
    "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v4"
}
```

...where instead, if you send it send it as [a JSON-encoded body as the documentation calls for](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/):

```
{"query":"query{repository(owner:\"ccjmk\", name:\"super-happiness\"){object(expression:\"master\"){... on Commit{history{totalCount}}}}}"}
```

It replies the expected 200 OK and JSON data:

```
{
    "data": {
        "repository": {
            "object": {
                "history": {
                    "totalCount": 19
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```